# IdentityServer3 authenticating client_credentials

Tags: identityserver3

I am trying to do something with the grant type **client_credentials**. I have set up everything and have a working client with it's flow set to **ClientCredentials** and added the required scopes.
I can get an access token fine, but what I would like to do is attach a user to the client when logging in.

When I log in as a user using the grant type **password**, my `CustomUserService` `AuthenticateLocalAsync` method is invoked, which get's the user and authenticates (I also add some claims, etc). But when I use the **client_credentials** grant type, that method is no longer invoked.

Does anyone know how I can do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Custom Grant Types](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customGrantTypes.html). I don't think that you can achieve it with out of the box flows, but maybe a custom grant type will work.